# Strange text size (change or scaling)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, text, sass, font-size

## Update

#### Ok so after trying the answer Muszla Provided

It looks like there is a scaling issue on mobile/small views. You can see that the text size gets set to 48px(which is what I want), but above it you can see the screen is rendering 57px. Any help figuring out why this is occurring would be awesome!

[image]

## Question before update

So I am having the weirdest front end issue that changes the text from say 20px to 43.81px. It seems it is based off of how long the title and content is. Doing a quick character count I get 276 characters that I need to have in the content section for this to re-size properly.

If I change the following example `Forgive me Father for I have sinned.............. "go on" says the priest. "I swore the other day" says the man. "continue" says the priest. "I was on the golf course the other day and i hit my drive, it was looking perfect, heading dead straight. About 200 yards down my ball` to that, but with only one l on the last word(aka ball to bal) then it shrinks back down to the size small size bellow. Any pointers as to what could be causing this issue would be great!

This is my scss

```
%faq-base {
  font-family: "BentonSans Regular", "Helvetica", arial, sans-serif; // This needs to be implemented in the @font-face
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
}

.title {
  @extend %faq-base;
}

.subtitle {
  @extend %faq-base;
  font-size: 20px
}

.faq {
  @extend %faq-base;
  margin: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;

  .question {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .answer {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}

a {
  color: #0091bb;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

This is the view

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2 class="subtitle"><%= @faq_category.name %></h2>
<div class="faq">
  <% @faq_category.faq_entries.each do |faq| %>
      <h3 class="question"><%= raw faq.question %></h3>
      <p class="answer"><%= raw faq.answer %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is an example of it working incorrectly, and then correctly.
[image: To Short] [image: Long Enough]

Comment: What you have posted is not CSS.

Comment: Nice catch, corrected

Comment: If this is a pure CSS problem, and not a Sass problem, only post the pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

It always will work strange. Remove this: Get ride of -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto; 
And use @media query and set correct font-size for correct window size:

example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .subtitle {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  .subtitle {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

Whats more you can wrap text inside container by:

```
.wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

Comment: That looks like it helps, but I am running into an interesting issue where it gets set at 48(The size I want) and then for some reason scaling that up to 57. I will add a picture of it above

Comment: also you should specify px after 700 and 701 in your @media lines

Comment: Yeah it was just an example how you can do it :) Check inside chrome console if something is not overwirte your font-size in this strange case

Comment: It has helped us identify the real issue, but still not sure how to solve it currently. I think I am putting it off until monday. Or what we hope is the issue haha